# Create a way to search a date range from JSON datetime

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, datetime

I've been battling this issue for the past few days, and I am stumped. Time to take it to you all.

My JSON data looks like this:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "0.1",
  "data": {
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 50,
    "count": 50,
    "total": 783,
    "reports": [
      {
        "type": "ROOM_CHARGE",
        "data": {
          "datetime": "2014-11-04T14:00:27-08:00",
          "originator": "639a",
          "roomNumber": "639",
          "chargeItem": "Premium Services",
          "chargeAmountCents": 495
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "STB_EVENT_TIMED",
        "data": {
          "datetime": "2014-11-04T12:58:38-08:00",
          "originator": "249b",
          "roomNumber": "249",
          "eventItem": "Watched movie 31008",
          "duration": "P0Y0M0DT1H12M18.907S"
        }
      },
```

I can display the data just fine, but I'm trying to create a way to search a date range from the `datetime` data in the JSON.

Here is what I have tried:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit_search'])){ 
  $room_number = $_GET['id'];
  $first_date = new DateTime($_GET['first_date']);
  $last_date = new DateTime($_GET['last_date']);
}

<?php foreach($output1['data']['reports'] as $reporting): ?>

    <!-- inside the date range -->
    <?php $report_date = new DateTime($reporting['data']['datetime']); ?>
    <?php if($first_date >= $report_date && $last_date <= $report_date): ?>

        <?php if($reporting['type'] == "ROOM_CHARGE"): ?>
          <tr>
          <td><?php echo 'Room Charge'; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $report_date; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $report_date->format('Y-m-d'); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $report_date->format('h:i:s A'); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo ($reporting['data']['roomNumber']) ?>  </td>
          <td><?php echo ($reporting['data']['originator']) ?>  </td>                            
          <td><?php echo ($reporting['data']['chargeItem']) ?></td>
          <td><?php echo number_format(($reporting['data']['chargeAmountCents'])/100, 2, '.', ',') ?></td>
          <td>-</td>              
          </tr>
        <?php elseif($reporting['type'] == "STB_EVENT_TIMED"): ?>
          <tr>
          <td><?php echo 'Event'; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $report_date->format('Y-m-d'); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $report_date->format('h:i:s A'); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo ($reporting['data']['roomNumber'])?>  </td>
          <td><?php echo ($reporting['data']['originator']) ?>  </td>                     
          <td><?php echo ($reporting['data']['eventItem']) ?></td>
          <td>-</td>   
          <td><?php echo substr($reporting['data']['duration'], -10, 2) ?>:<?php echo substr($reporting['data']['duration'], -7, 2) ?>:<?php echo substr($reporting['data']['duration'], -4, 2) ?></td>                
          </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

the `$first_date` and `$last_date` are set to whatever a user enters in a form, in the format 2014-11-05 xxxx-xx-xx

**ANY** help would be appreciated. I can provide more code, or anything else you need. Thank you for checking out my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to substring each date, you could use `DateTime` classes in this case, then you could compare them inside the if conditions:

Simple example:

```
<?php

$json_string = '{"apiVersion": "0.1","data": {"offset": 0,"limit": 50,"count": 50,"total": 783,"reports": [{"type": "ROOM_CHARGE","data": {"datetime": "2014-11-04T14:00:27-    08:00","originator": "639a","roomNumber": "639","chargeItem": "Premium Services","chargeAmountCents": 495}},{"type": "STB_EVENT_TIMED","data": {"datetime": "2014-11-04T12:58:38-    08:00","originator": "249b","roomNumber": "249","eventItem": "Watched movie 31008","duration": "P0Y0M0DT1H12M18.907S"}}]}}';
$first_date = new DateTime($_GET['first_date'] . '-08:00'); // post/get user input values
$last_date = new DateTime($_GET['last_date'] . '-08:00');
$last_date->setTime(23, 59, 59);

$output1 = json_decode($json_string, true);

?>
<?php foreach($output1['data']['reports'] as $reporting): ?>
    <!-- inside the date range -->
    <?php $report_date = new DateTime($reporting['data']['datetime']); ?>
    <?php if($report_date >= $first_date && $report_date <= $last_date): ?>
        <?php if($reporting['type'] == "ROOM_CHARGE"): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo 'Room Charge'; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $report_date->format('Y-m-d'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $report_date->format('h:i:s A'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($reporting['data']['roomNumber']) ?> </td>
                <td><?php echo ($reporting['data']['originator']) ?> </td>
                <td><?php echo ($reporting['data']['chargeItem']) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo number_format(($reporting['data']['chargeAmountCents'])/100, 2, '.', ',') ?></td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
        <?php elseif($reporting['type'] == "STB_EVENT_TIMED"): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo 'Event'; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $report_date->format('Y-m-d'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $report_date->format('h:i:s A'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($reporting['data']['roomNumber'])?> </td>
                <td><?php echo ($reporting['data']['originator']) ?> </td>
                <td><?php echo ($reporting['data']['eventItem']) ?></td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td><?php echo substr($reporting['data']['duration'], -10, 2) ?>:<?php echo substr($reporting['data']['duration'], -7, 2) ?>:<?php echo substr($reporting['data']['duration'],     -4, 2) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Supplemental info:

Once its a `DateTime` object, you could now use its method:

```
<td><?php echo $report_date->format('Y-m-d'); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $report_date->format('h:i:s A'); ?></td>
```

Comment: thank you for trying. I appreciate your help, for sure. I tried using the <?php if($report_date >= $first_date && $report_date <= $last_date): ?> and I am getting a syntax error, "unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND)". I definitely see what you are saying here, and I will keep trying.

Comment: @ValleyDigital you sure you copied it right? check it out here http://codepad.viper-7.com/xo7PvW

Comment: I copied it right. I am still working on it, though. I don't understand the DateTime well enough. When I try to echo report_date I get "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string". Your code worked, it was my fault, sorry.

Comment: @ValleyDigital yes thats the correct behavior, when its a `DateTime` object now, its now an object and therefore you cannot directly echo it anymore as it is not a string. don't compare dates as string, either convert them to seconds or use datetime objects as they are directly comparable inside the if condition

Comment: Ok, I see. I can compare them, and then still echo the substring?

Comment: @ValleyDigital don't worry you can turn them back into a string again by using its method `echo $report_date->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: @ValleyDigital by the way i made a demo, so that you could see it in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/xo7PvW

Comment: @ValleyDigital don't directly echo the `$report_date`, its an object now look at my revision

Comment: thank you for your help on this. I appreciate it more than you know. I updated my original question, so far it's not bringing back any data at all, but I get no errors.

Comment: @ValleyDigital and make sure `$first_date` and `$last_date` are `DateTime` objects also so that they can be converted, by the way, what are there values anyway?

Comment: I actually don't get any errors, but no data is displayed. Not sure where to go from here. I have updated my question with everything we have talked about. If you can look at the updated question, maybe you can see why it's not echo anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64359/discussion-between-ghost-and-valleydigital).

Comment: Ok, i'm there. Thank you

Comment: thank you again for helping me solve this issue. Turns out it was a timezone issue. You are the best! Ever!

Comment: @ValleyDigital no prob, glad it turned out well.